# How to set up a default value in p-dropdown?

Tags: angular, p-dropdown

The p-dropdown below is reading json data from API. Among the data values, I want to set up "apple" by default. Currently, in the p-dropdown, the first thing users can see is the placeholder value (i.e "Select a Product").

How can I preset a default value in p-dropdown? Any help or advice, please?

```js
                <p-dropdown
                  [options]="products"
                  optionLabel="productName"
                  optionValue="productId"
                  placeholder="Select a Product"
                  [filter]="true"
                  filterBy="productName"
                ></p-dropdown>
```

```json
[
    {
        productName: "apple",
        productId: 1
    },
    {
        productName: "banana",
        productId: 2
    },
    {
        productName: "watermelon",
        productId: 3
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ngModel` to tie your current `selectedItem` to the `dropdown` selected item and viceversa.

```
<p-dropdown
  [options]="products"
  optionLabel="productName"
  optionValue="productId"
  placeholder="Select a Product"
  [filter]="true"
  filterBy="productName"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct" // Add this line
></p-dropdown>
```

It's important that you do add that property to your Angular component, in order to be able to use it.

**Edit:**
Here's an example for your component:

```
interface Product {
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
}

@Component({
  ...
})
export class DropdownDemo {
  public products: Product[] = [
    {
      productName: 'apple',
      productId: 1,
    },
    {
      productName: 'banana',
      productId: 2,
    },
    {
      productName: 'watermelon',
      productId: 3,
    },
  ];
  public selectedProduct: Product; // This is what you'd use for your [(ngModel)]
}
```

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: I am still confused. Can you give me how the part of ts should look like?

Comment: I'll update my answer with an example